# Typed JS error with german umlauts and special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a huge problem. I'm using Typed JS on my website. The problem is that it looks like Typed JS don't supports special characters or german umlauts. Here is an example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  new Typed("#umlauts-special-chars",{strings:["","Deine Plattform füüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüür GT & Heimaufträge"],typeSpeed:60,loop:!1});
  new Typed("#no-umlauts-special-chars",{strings:["","Welcome on my special plattform with a long long text"],typeSpeed:60,loop:!1});
});
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.10/typed.min.js" integrity="sha256-F6VRM94CIE3Kv2zkAtbzlViDfZ3HMaIgusIcFBPIjiU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="umlauts-special-chars"></div>
  <div id="no-umlauts-special-chars"></div>
</div>
```

Has anyone an idea how I can fix this? This is absolutely important for me because I've a release this night. So hopefully someone can help me or has knowledge about this.

Comment: Your example fails to show any error on my browser (Chrome/Mac). You need to describe the problem; right now, it seems to me like you're complaining the code works correctly..? How specifically does it not support them, what happens, do you have an error message, are they badly rendered, do you have encoding issues, what browser are you on...?

Comment: Check the first line. It stops at the & sign

Comment: How is that connected to german umlauts at all?... Replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Comment: @Amadan Maybe this should be part of the plugins readme file. What do you think?

Comment: Since I am not the developer of that plugin (and haven't even heard about it till today), it hardly matters what I think. If you have a strong opinion on it, leave an issue on the Github project, rather than litigating it on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not caused by the German letters. It is caused by HTML coding. It worked for me coding to HTML using a textarea coding trick.

```
function encodeHtml(html) {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.textContent = html;
    const encodedHtml = textarea.innerHTML;
    textarea.remove();
    return encodedHtml;
};

encodeHtml("Deine Plattform füüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüür GT & Heimaufträge")
// return 'Deine Plattform füüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüür GT &amp; Heimaufträge'
```

I didn't get to test which browser works, but it seems to work in all. Anyway, you can test it out.

```
let supportEncodeHtml = false
if(encodeHtml('&') === '&amp;'){
     supportEncodeHtml= true
}
```